# fatal: failed to read object X Input/output error fatal: index-pack failed - Git pull with Dropbox

Tags: git, dropbox

I moved my git repo into a Dropbox shared account. And since then, each time I do a `git pull` I get the following error:

```sh
fatal: failed to read object e1ad9cbb1cb523a82191acd817fdc68d0388a45e: Input/output error
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Do you guys know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I actually found the issue.

Since Dropbox added its new feature *Smart Sync* You need to make sure all your files in your `.git` are synced locally.

Comment: You sir, are a legend!

Comment: Ahah glad it helped !

Comment: Another thing that helped me with this issue was running `git gc`. That cleaned up a ton of residual objects in the .git/objects directory that were taking a long time to sync.

Comment: I have been ripping my hair out for 3 days not figuring this our, thank you!!!

Comment: My fear of losing everything disappeared after I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are my hero