# git error `fatal: failed to read object` when pushing from a repo on Dropbox on a new machine

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on my old computer stored on Dropbox. I recently bought a new computer (which I currently don't have access to), downloaded Dropbox, synced the repository folder from Dropbox, and tried to make changes and push them to the repository. However, I receive the error:

```
fatal: failed to read object 21519a1bca9bbabb1c3185336a974cedca25b0dc: Input/output error
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/my-repo.git'
```

(where I have changed the actual username/repo name).

There are some other questions about these failures, but nothing I could find as simple as my situation. Using git with Dropbox is sometimes cautioned, but this seems to be unexpected behaviour as far as I can tell.

I've tried searching for the objects referred to but I can't find them in the stream of other objects in `.git/objects`.

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question using the answer here: [fatal: failed to read object X Input/output error fatal: index-pack failed - Git pull with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553945/fatal-failed-to-read-object-x-input-output-error-fatal-index-pack-failed-git)

Even though I thought my whole repository had been synced locally, going into the `.git` file showed that only some folders had been synced locally by 'Smart sync'. Right-clicking and choosing `Smart sync -> local` for each folder not locally synced fixed the issue.

Comment: Given that Git creates and destroys these various subdirectories ("folders") inside `.git` whenever it feels like doing so, it looks like one of the many reasons not to put your `.git` into a Dropbox area is that you're going to have to click around like this all day every day...

Comment: Yes, very true @torek. I suppose I've gotten used to Dropbox for all my work!